# Подключить два типа фрагментов в recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview.adapter

Всем доброго времени суток, есть такая задача - в recyclerView нужно добавить какой-то список товаров и фрагмент кнопки последний заказ (обновить или подгрузить следующие 10 товаров, не суть). Привести их к какому-то базовому абстрактному классу тоже не получится ибо в дальнейшем для товаров будут применяться фильтры и фрагмент "кнопки" в этом списке явно не нужен. include - выбивает отшибку типа recyclerView no LayoutManager. Вот такой код сделал уже (список товаров рендерит, а фрагмент кнопки не добавляет):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_FRAGMENT, container, false);

    ConnecterDTO connecterDTO = new ConnecterDTO();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManagerVertical;

    staggeredGridLayoutManagerVertical = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    // error - recyclerView.addView(new LastPurchasesFragment().getView());
    // no result - 
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_filtr, container, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManagerVertical);

    TovarListAdapter tovarListAdapter = new TovarListAdapter(getContext(), connecterDTO.getItemTovars());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(tovarListAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Вот код TovarListAdapter

```
public class TovarListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<TovarListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ItemTovar> itemTovarList;

public TovarListAdapter(Context context, List <ItemTovar>  list){
    itemTovarList = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tovar_item, parent, false);

    //getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_filtr, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemTovar item = itemTovarList.get(position);
    holder.tovName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.tovPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
    holder.tovImage.setImageResource(item.getImageTovar());

    if(item.isSaleOrange()){
        holder.saleOrange.setText(item.getTextSale());
        holder.saleOrange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(item.isSaleRed()){
        holder.saleRed.setText(item.getTextSale());
        holder.saleRed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemTovarList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tovName;
    TextView tovPrice;
    ImageView tovImage;
    TextView saleOrange;
    TextView saleRed;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tovName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tovarItemName);
        tovPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tovarItemPrice);
        tovImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tovarItemImage);
        saleOrange = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaleOrange);
        saleRed = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaleRed);
    }
}
}
```

Напрямую в recyclerView вставить хардкодом relativeLayout так же не получается(
Подскажите пожалуйста как зарендерить два типа фрагментов. Если нужно больше кода - вот ссылка на github: [проект](https://github.com/Divinkas/tst.git) Спасибо заранее!

Comment: а почему бы кнопку не вынести за `RecyclerView`? она явно вне его логики

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет библиотека https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/wiki/Quick-start-with-the-Renderer-Adapter
Определяете две viewmodel, для каждой свое поведение и layout и отдаёт массив с ними.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавлять:

```
recyclerView.addView(new LastPurchasesFragment().getView());
```

после

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManagerVertical);
```

а в целом какая-то королевская у вас кнопка, что вы её в отдельный фрагмент вынесли, ну это ваше личное...